# Using ReactiveUI, how can I bind a DataContext to a View used in another View?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveUI and Gemini Framework in my project and I'm trying to display a View within another View, but I can't bind the View Model to that Child View.

I tried to just instatiate the Child View Model in the Main View Model and then Bind it to the View, which I add as a UserControl.

In the main View Model:`

```
public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel= new ChildViewModel();
```

In the Main View:

```
<views:ChildView DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

When I use the binding I get the following Error:

ReactiveUI.UnhandledErrorException: 'An object implementing IHandleObservableErrors (often a ReactiveCommand or ObservableAsPropertyHelper) has errored, thereby breaking its observable pipeline. To prevent this, ensure the pipeline does not error, or Subscribe to the ThrownExceptions property of the object in question to handle the erroneous case.'

Inner Exception

NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.

Comment: I think this error has nothing to do with the child view - take a look at the stack trace of the exception, it should tell you in which line in which file exactly you have null reference

Comment: Also it looks like your not using INotifyPropertyChanged, in ReactiveUI you get this for free with ReactiveObject.

Comment: thanks man... the problem was literally me just doing a null refernece in the ctor of the child vm

Comment: You may want to add that as a answer. Usually it avoids people accidentally attempting to answer it from now. Or just delete the question I guess.